# filter unbound when using [] blank node notation?

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I am trying to get entities from the Drug Ontology that **have an ingredient**, using restrictions like

- `OBI_0000576` 'scattered molecular aggregate'
- `BFO_0000053` 'is bearer of'
- `BFO_0000071` 'has granular part'

**but don't have** a mass (`PATO_0000125`) specified.  An example of that would be 'Acetaminophen / Hydrocodone Oral Tablet' 
 http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00020585 , **but not** 'Acetaminophen 230 MG / Hydrocodone 5 MG Oral Tablet' http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DRON_00038671

I have implemented this as a minus operation with two previously developed queries

I have gotten into the habit of referring to the owl restrictions as blank nodes, instead of giving them variables

This query is running slow (45 minutes on a server with SSD and 64 GB RAM).  I'd like to merge the queries together and filter out patterns that have a mass specified.  I figure I'll need to specify the `rdf:rest` of the intersection that mentions mass, using a variable inside an optional {} clause, and then filtering for cases where that variable isn't bound.

***I don't see how to do that inside the [] blank node notation?  Is it possible?***

`PREFIX obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select ?d ?dl 
where {
    {
        ?d rdfs:label ?dl ;
           rdfs:subClassOf   [ owl:onProperty <http://www.obofoundry.org/ro/ro.owl#has_proper_part> ;
            owl:someValuesFrom [ owl:intersectionOf [ rdf:first
                obo:OBI_0000576 ;
            rdf:rest [ rdf:first [ owl:onProperty obo:BFO_0000053 ] ;
            rdf:rest [ rdf:first [ owl:onProperty
                obo:BFO_0000071 ;
            owl:someValuesFrom ?c ] ] ] ] ] ] .
    } minus  {
        ?prod rdfs:label ?l ;
              rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:someValuesFrom [  owl:intersectionOf [  rdf:rest [ rdf:rest [ rdf:first [  owl:onProperty obo:BFO_0000053 ;
            owl:someValuesFrom [ owl:intersectionOf  [ rdf:first <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/PATO_0000125> ]  ] ]   ]  ]  ] ] ] .
        ?d rdfs:subClassOf* ?prod ;
                          rdfs:label ?dl .
    }
}`

Comment: Mark, is this an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You could remove patterns with `rdfs:label` at least... And, imho, `FILTER NOT EXISTS` is more readable than `MINUS`.

Comment: Also, [this syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#collections) improves readability.

Comment: minimal?  besides the labels, i **think** all of those statements are necessary for my semantics.

Comment: complete and verifiable?  you should be able to run it at http://sparql.hegroup.org/sparql/, but I expect that would be extremely slow, so it may not be a tolerable example

Comment: I was purposely using the square brackets instead of collection notation.  I think it mirrors the owl Manchester notation nicely.  But maybe it really isn't  a  good choice.  I'll rewrite it and show my progress later today or tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: @MarkMiller Your current solution looks like being hard-coded regarding the parts of the intersection. I don't think this will work as you'd have to know in advance then at which position in the list the `mass` is located. The common pattern to handle intersections is the property path`owl:intersectionOf/
    rdf:rest*/rdf:first` maybe with some trailing `/owl:someValuesFrom ?fillerCls`

Comment: Note, your query returns results in less than 1s on the endpoint you've listed (I used `http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/merged/DRON` as default graph) - but I guess the result itself is wrong

Comment: @AKSW  thanks for the feedback.  for me, wihtout specifying a named graph, both the first half of the query (has an ingredient) and the second half (has mass) run nicely on http://sparql.hegroup.org/sparql/ , but the full `minus` query fails because the server doesn't have enough memory

Comment: @MarkMiller. in other words, you are asking, is it possible to write something like `[OPTIONAL {:p :q}]`? What about putting *everything* into `OPTIONAL` instead of `MINUS`?